# Restrict Apache forward proxy to a remote url set

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, access-control-list, remote, url

Is there a robust way to restrict Apache forward proxy to a set of remote URLs?

Now I can see the only solution with multiple identical `<Proxy "...">` blocks as:

```
<Proxy "http://example1.com">
...
</Proxy>
<Proxy "http://example2.com">
...
</Proxy>
<Proxy "http://example3.com">
...
</Proxy>
```

-- that is not suitable.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: you can use wildcards and regex with ProxyMatch, how many entries in that set you are refering to?

Comment: @DanielFerradal it will be more than dozen I think